# Canvas size of IText

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I'm working on project for Canvas editor. I'm using IText to add text in a canvas. The user can change Font, make text bold italic and so on. The problem when user want to change Font Size of the text he can but the text change not in px size. If is needed I can put all code. And can show the live version.To change size at now I use this code

```js
document.getElementById('fontSize').onchange = function() {
  canvas.getActiveObject().set("FontSize", this.value);
  canvas.renderAll();
}
```

```html
<div class="select-wrapper font-size">
  <select id="fontSize">
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
    <option value="16">16</option>
    <option value="18">18</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="22">22</option>
    <option value="24">24</option>
    <option value="26">26</option>
    <option value="28">28</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
    <option value="32">32</option>
    <option value="34">34</option>
    <option value="36">36</option>
    <option value="38">38</option>
    <option value="40">40</option>
    <option value="42">42</option>
    <option value="44">44</option>
    <option value="46">46</option>
    <option value="48">48</option>
    <option value="50">50</option>
    <option value="52">52</option>
    <option value="54">54</option>
    <option value="56">56</option>
    <option value="58">58</option>
    <option value="60">60</option>
    <option value="62">62</option>
    <option value="64">64</option>
    <option value="66">66</option>
    <option value="68">68</option>
    <option value="70">70</option>
    <option value="72">72</option>
    <option value="74">74</option>
    <option value="76">76</option>
    <option value="78">78</option>
    <option value="80">80</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry, but your assumption is wrong, please take this answer as a long comment,

> The problem when user want to change Font Size of the text he can but
>   the text change not in px size.

as you can read in the [fabric.js source code](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.js.html#line21154):

```
/**
* Font size (in pixels)
* @type Number
* @default
*/
fontSize:             40,
```

the default (*Ed. and unique*) unit is in pixel.

If you run the executable snippet below you can see the fabric iText, and input text, update their font size in sync

```js
$(function() {
  var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
  var iTextSample = new fabric.IText('hello\nworld', {
    left: 50,
    top: 50,
    fontFamily: 'Helvetica',
    fontSize: $('#fontSize').val(),
  });
  $('#dText').css('fontSize', $('#fontSize').val() + 'px');

  canvas.add(iTextSample);
  canvas.setActiveObject(iTextSample);
  $('#fontSize').change(
    function() {
      $('#dText').css('fontSize', this.value + 'px');
      canvas.getActiveObject().set("fontSize", this.value);
      canvas.renderAll();
    });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.6.4/fabric.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="150" height="150" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);"></canvas>

<select id="fontSize">
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="12">12</option>
  <option value="14">14</option>
  <option value="16">16</option>
  <option value="18">18</option>
  <option value="20">20</option>
  <option value="22">22</option>
  <option value="24">24</option>
  <option value="26">26</option>
  <option value="28">28</option>
  <option value="30">30</option>
</select>

<input id="dText" value="hello world">
```

Comment: Thank you, for the help.